# Count number of coloured cells in column with dynamic number of rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

At the bottom of each column I'm trying to display how many cells in that column have a particular background colour. This is what I'd like it to do:
[Picture of intended result](http://postimg.org/image/ltn9ojtgb/)

The problem is it's a Gantt chart and I'll be inserting rows constantly. I can do it with a fixed number of rows using:

```
=countCellsWithBackgroundColor("#cfe2f3", "B1:B22")
```

which uses this function I found:

```
function countCellsWithBackgroundColor(color, rangeSpecification) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);

  var x = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {

      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);

      if(cell.getBackgroundColor() == color)
        x++;
    }
  }

  return x;
}
```

I just can't figure out how to give that function every cell in the column. I get errors like "must be a range".

Comment: Does using an open-ended range like `=countCellsWithBackgroundColor("#cfe2f3";"B:B")` not work?

Comment: Oh god. Thank you. I so focused on getting the last cell in the column that by the time I figured out I could just use the whole row it didn't even occur to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a more efficient way to achieve the same result by using arrays in your function like below

```
function countCellsWithBackgroundColor(color, rangeSpecification) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var backGroundColors = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification).getBackgrounds();

  var x = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < backGroundColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < backGroundColors[0].length; j++) {

      if(backGroundColors[i][j] == color){ x++ }
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Serge - I've noticed that formula will cache the results for a range and not update the value. It also requires you to modify the formula to include a different range to refresh the values. Can you replicate that behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

[WORKING EXAMPLE WITH AUTO UPDATE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWg_w2bDtHVdKhMpjv-b_ywXDl1A0F1iwr2KZKMMmtc/edit#gid=0)

```
function countCellsWithBackgroundColor(color, rangeSpecification) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var backGroundColors = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification).getBackgrounds();

var x = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < backGroundColors.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < backGroundColors[0].length; j++) {

  if(backGroundColors[i][j] == color){ x++ }
   }
 }
 return x;
}

function onEdit(e)
{
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('H26').setValue(Math.random());
}
```

Now Insert the dummy cell into spreadsheet function for auto update

```
=countCellsWithBackgroundColor("#0f9d58","A5:A26",H26)
```